# Converting a defined structure into double (complex numbers) in c++

Tags: c++, struct, double, complex-numbers

Im trying to find my way around defining structures, and coded this to define a complex number. Ive already had success working with them, adding multiplying e.g., but I dont know how to get the absolute value of my complex number converted into a double, my compiler keeps telling me it doesnt know how to convert it, even though the complex struct is literally made of 2 doubles..

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

struct Complex_Number { 
    double re, im;      
};
void print(const Complex_Number& w) //my print function for complex numbers
{
    cout  << '(' << w.re << " + i*" << w.im << ')';
}

 double abs(const Complex_Number& z )
{

   z = z.re + z.im;
  abs = sqrt((z.re*z.re)+(z.im*z.im)); 

   return abs;
   }




  int main()
{

 return 0;




}
```

Comment: `abs` is the name of the function - i.e. a function pointer - you need to create a double variable.

Comment: See [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex).

Comment: As @ThomasMatthews mentions, you should check out your local `std::complex<double>` to see how the interfaces can be defined by your standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you intend with `z = z.re + z.im`; The second part just needs to be assigned to a variable or returned directly. So write...

```
double abs(const Complex_Number& z ) {

  double ret = sqrt((z.re*z.re)+(z.im*z.im)); 

  return ret;
}
```

or

```
double abs(const Complex_Number& z ) {

  return sqrt((z.re*z.re)+(z.im*z.im)); 
}
```

Assigning something to the "function name" as in your code, i.e. `abs = sqrt((z.re*z.re)+(z.im*z.im))`, is not valid C++ code.

Comment: Whoah thanks for that.. i have spent too much time today that i literally blocked myself from seeing this obvious one.. i really appreciate your help!